# Как называется View карточки на первом фрагменте?

Tags: android, android-fragment

У меня есть задание сверстать это в Android Studio (см. скрин) и у меня есть пару вопросов. Как называется View карточки на первом фрагменте? То есть чтобы на ней находились элементы и она была кликабельна. Я понял то что на скринах это 2 отдельных фрагмента, но что должно быть в activity_main.xml? Только контейнер FrameLayout? А всю работу с фрагментами наверное через beginTransaction()? Только как при запуске приложения отобразить сразу фрагмент1? А вот это для меня загадка:
- У активности должен быть Toolbar с colorPrimary цветом
- каждый фрагмент должен менять заголовок в Toolbar: ContactListFragment -> "Список контактов", ContactDetailsFragment -> "Детали контакта"
Помогите хоть с чем-то пожалуйста)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На первом скрине какой-то то виджет списка: RecyclerView, ListView  и т.п. , сама карточка одного айтема списка - сейчас модно использовать CardView, но может быть любой подходящий контейнер. Судя по вашим вопросам вы слабо понимаете, что и как вам нужно делать. Советую почитать книгу Б. Филлипс "Android. Программирование для профессионалов", там очень подробно (практически по шагам) разбирается создание похожего приложения Criminal Intent, работа с фрагментами, тулбаром и вот это вот все.

Comment: В рамках данного ресурса вы задали слишком общий вопрос, так же, по правилам данного ресурса вопрос должен содержать **одну конкретную проблему**, а не что то вроде "расскажите, как мне написать приложение"

Answer (score 1):

Фрагмент может храниться в любой View.

Самый классический случай это FrameLayout с id (например container). В которой вы кладете ваш фрагмент.

```
getSupportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction ()
    .add(fragment, R.id.container) //тут могу ошибаться в порядке аргументов, пишу по памяти.
    .commit()
```

Если же вам необходимо чтоб у вас был ещё какой-то общий для нескольких фрагментов элемент (например toolbar) то вы можете его положить над вашим FrameLayout в активити.

Вы так же можете в одну активити класть более одного фрагмента. Важно понимать, что они не привязаны к какому-то одному типу View в рамках одной активити.

Другой вопрос это взаимодействие этих фрагментов с Activity и другими фрагментами, но это отдельная тема и она выходит за рамки этого вопроса.